# session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id - session is not active

Tags: session

In one of my PHP LOGIN page, I am using below code. I am using PHP Version : 7.3

Recently My Web Provider Migrated my server to a new server. After Migration, It was working fine. But after 12 hours, I see this error Now.

```
<?php
if(session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)
    { 
    // Finally, destroy the session.
       session_start(); 
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION);
    session_regenerate_id(true);
       session_start(); 
        foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val)
        echo $key." -".$val."<br/>";    
}
?>
```

Error :

> Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id -
> session is not active in /email/PHPMailer/index0.php on line 8
>
> Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already
> sent in /email/PHPMailer/index0.php on line 9
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
> /email/PHPMailer/index0.php on line 10

Comment: It seems that PHP will emit `Cannot regenerate session id - session is not active` from `session_regenerate_id()` if the directory to store the session is not writable.

Answer (score 2):

You can't regenerate an ID for a non-existent session because you destroyed it.Try switching lines 8 and 9 like this.

```
if(session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)
{ 
// Finally, destroy the session.
   session_start(); 
   session_destroy();
   unset($_SESSION);
   session_start(); 
   session_regenerate_id(true);
   foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val)
      echo $key." -".$val."<br/>";    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On my case the issue was related to the permission of the folder `/var/lib/php/session` that php uses to store session data. I fixed the issue by changing the permissions to `777`:

```
chmod -R 777 /var/lib/php/session
```

You can limit the permissions to `744` that also works fine.

I hope this will help someone else.